# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar un error de Realm cuando quiero agregar una clase?

Tags: java, realm

En el momento de agregar una clase nueva con extensión RealmObject a mi proyecto y ejecutarlo deja de funcionar y me muestra este error:

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is
>   required due to the following errors: - Class 'DatosPost' has been
>   added.

Esta es mi clase:

```
public class DatosPost extends RealmObject {

    private String alfanumerico;
    private String descripcion;
    private String fechaActualizacion;
    private String parametro;

    public String getAlfanumerico() {
        return alfanumerico;
    }

    public void setAlfanumerico(String alfanumerico) {
        this.alfanumerico = alfanumerico;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getFechaActualizacion() {
        return fechaActualizacion;
    }

    public void setFechaActualizacion(String fechaActualizacion) {
        this.fechaActualizacion = fechaActualizacion;
    }

    public String getParametro() {
        return parametro;
    }

    public void setParametro(String parametro) {
        this.parametro = parametro;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amiga lo que debes de hacer es desintestinar la aplicación y luego reinstalarla siendo esta la solución más fácil.
Existe otra solución que es establecer en tu configuración de Real la migración para lo cual te recomiendo leer la documentación en la siguiente pagina.
[Documentación Oficial Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

Haciendo énfasis  en la parte de la configuración
Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias por el dato, si ya había encontrado que tengo de desinstalar la aplicación y volver a instalar, leeré el link que pusiste. Soy mujer (es que pusiste amigo).

Comment: @Mandy Perdón pero nunca leo los user name cualquier cosa estamos para ayudarte